# Xcode, have delegate method auto-include classes

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, delegates

In Xcode I would like to add a delegate such as `UITextFieldDelegate` and have methods such as `textFieldShouldReturn` auto added to my document

In Java when I include an interface, my IDE typically forces me to auto-add some particular classes, which I tend to add code into.

Is there any way to do this in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the methods in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol are optional, so Xcode won't give you any warnings. If you try something like `UITableViewDataSource`, you'll see Xcode gives you warnings for the required methods that your class hasn't implemented.

I don't know of a way to auto-fill those methods, but it's really easy to cmd+click `UITextFieldDelegate` and copy/paste the methods you need. It's possible that there is an Xcode plugin out there that would auto-fill the required methods for you.